# SQL to generate range of valid values between 2 known integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to write a SQL query that will generate a list of valid integers given the start and end to the range.

ie given the below table :-

```
CMPY------MIN_YEAR------MAX_YEAR
PS--------2007----------2014
```

I'd like to write a query which would return all valid values (against CMPY) ie :-

```
CMPY  YEAR
PS    2007
PS    2008
PS    2009
PS    2010
PS    2011
PS    2012
PS    2013
PS    2014
```

This needs to work on both Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you want this for sql server or for oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a portable solution you may want to create a simple table of numbers like this:

```
create table integers (val integer);
```

then populate it with as many rows as you may ever need.  Then your query is:

```
select t.cmpy, i.val
from mytable t
join integers i on i.val between t.min_year and t.max_year;
```

Comment: gone with this method due to portability

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Oracle without any table (You can use the table way for SQL Server):

```
SELECT a.cmpy, (a.min_year - 1) + LEVEL MIN_YEAR 
    FROM  YOUR_TABLE  a
  CONNECT BY (LEVEL-1) <= (MAX_YEAR - MIN_YEAR)
```

e.g:

```
SELECT a.cmpy, (a.min_year - 1) + LEVEL MIN_YEAR 
    FROM (
                  SELECT 'PS' CMPY, 2007 MIN_YEAR, 2014 MAX_YEAR
                  FROM DUAL
                ) a
  CONNECT BY (LEVEL-1) <= (MAX_YEAR - MIN_YEAR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your data, the numbers are years.  You could create a table in both servers that contains all years, and then join on it:

```
select  year.YearNr
from    YourTable yt
join    YearTable year
on      year.YearNr between yt.StartDate and yt.EndDate
```

This effectively creates a row for each year in between, on both Oracle and SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to do this is to have a Numbers(int num) table that you can query to get a range of numbers, e.g.:

```
SELECT C.CMPY, N.num
FROM CMPY AS C
JOIN Numbers AS N
  ON N.num BETWEEN C.MIN_YEAR AND C.MAX_YEAR
```

Comment: Gone with similar solution due to portability